# PostgreSQL: Correct way for subset calculations

Tags: postgresql

I have a huge table (around 10 million items). For simplicity, let's say it has only 2 columns: `user_id` and `activity_id` like this

```
user_id | activity_id
---------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
```

I want to select all `user_id` with `activity_id = 1, 2 NOT 3`. In the case above it will be just one result: `user_id = 2`. I can do it using `SELECT DISTINCT` combined with `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` operators, but it seems to be extremely slow.

From what I know about databases, it can be improved with GIN and table partitioning, however I feel like it's not correct solution in the case of PostgreSQL (because subsets operators are slow by their own).

Comment: Please post your table(s) definition(s), query, and execution plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `activity_id=4` changes nothing in such a case. It's 10.000.000 rows.

Comment: When you say `activity id = 1, 2` do you mean 1 AND 2, or 1 OR 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with arrays in Postgres:

```
select user_id, array_agg(activity_id) as activities
from users
group by user_id
having array_agg(activity_id) @> array[1,2]
   and not 3 = any(array_agg(activity_id));
```

---

The condition `array_agg(activity_id) @> array[1,2]` only returns those that have activity_ids 1 and 2  and the condition `not 3 = any(array_agg(activity_id))` removes all those that contain `activity_id = 3`

If the table contains more than just those two columns, an index on `(user_id, activitiy_id)` will help as it enables Postgres to use an "Index Only Scan" instead of a full table scan. If there are only **very** users that have activity_ids 1 and two, an additional condition that only returns rows with either one of them (e.g. using a `where exists` condition) might help as it reduces the number of rows that need to be aggregated. In that case the index should be on `(activity_id, user_id)` to enable Postgres to remove unwanted rows efficiently.

On a table with 100.000 rows this ran in about 100ms on my laptop with Postgres 11 and a SSD.

Online example: https://rextester.com/YLN7221

Answer (score 2):

You can first try to rewrite the query using `EXISTS` and a regular (B-tree) index on `user_id` and `activity_id`.

```
CREATE INDEX elbat_user_id_activity_id
             ON elbat (user_id,
                       activity_id);
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM elbat t2
                            WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                                  AND t2.activity_id = '1')
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                                      AND t2.activity_id = '2')
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM elbat t2
                                    WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                                          AND t2.activity_id = '3');
```

If you have a user table, you might also want to join to that instead of retrieving the distinct user ID from the other table.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, seems like having index on two columns gives great perfomance boost. But the answer I've selected still seems to be more "correct". One more time, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) for this.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING bool_or(activity_id IN (1,2))  -- assumes '1, 2' mean '1 OR 2'
  AND NOT bool_or(activity_id IN (3));
```